# Get build from TFS 2012 build definition

Tags: tfs, build, definition

I am new at TFS 2012. I create build definition for getting build but I can be success.
I am getting some errors. These  errors with regard to telerik component. TFS build definition  can not read telerik .dll(can't read RadGrid). My TFS  works on another  remote server, I try to getting build on my local Pc(I got the project my local pc with get last recursive). I ceckhing everything afterwards  I start new build. 
I wonder that When I start to new build on build definition,TFS use to local machine dll or remote machine dll ?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Telerik software on your build server (either that or you need to check-in all necessary Telerik DLL's for the build so the build server has access to them).

Comment: Or, ideally, manage binary dependencies out of a locally-hosted NuGet repo.